# Python program not running after launched as administrator

Tags: python, shell, sockets, operating-system, ctypes

```
import ctypes, sys
import webbrowser

def main():
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com')


def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False


if is_admin():
    main()
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

This is the whole 'test' code I made to test what was going wrong. Since I could not see any 'print' functions working on the python window as well as my IDE(PyCharm), I tested if the program was working by opening a website. If the program is run without admin rights (so when I removed the `if is_admin()` part of the code), it works like a charm. However if run with the admin rights function, it does not perform anything and just exits with exit code 0 (according to PyCharm). I figured no program code was executed after the `ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)`. I hope someone can figure how to solve the problem.
My OS is Windows 10.

I guess the open website idea wasn't that good. So I also tried to have the file to create a test_success.txt file. Without the admin option it works, but with admin nothing happens. In this case, even if the process was terminated right after execution the file should remain to determine its success.

Comment: Presumably, the browser is immediately closed as the application terminates. Use ShellExecuteW in all cases.

Comment: Your code works for me with no changes.  the elevated window exits, but the page comes up in my browser (Chome).  I ran the script at the Windows command prompt, not PyCharm.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is not the case because I have also tested with creating a local file. Python can't possibly delete a file after it is run.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I also have it running! But the thing is, it only runs when I execute the code using Windows CMD, not when I run the code from the file manager. Do you have any idea how?

Comment: No, but add some prints for `sys.executable` and `sys.argv` and some `input()` statements to pause the code before launch and the end of the script to view the values and keep the windows open and see if there is any difference in the run methods.  Also, how *exactly* do you run from command line vs. from the "file manager"?  It could be the default program used to run from, say, explorer.exe, is different from what you launch at the command line.

Comment: @MarkTolonen No luck on adding prints or input(). It seems to all get ignored. When I go into the file directory and launch it by the 'usual double click' then it fails to launch. Same for when I use the 'run' on PyCharm. The expected behavior of the program only appears when I use the command line on the directory with `python test.py`

Comment: The associated program for .py files is not registered properly for Python. What are the results of `assoc .py` from the command line? For the value reported, what is `ftype <that_value>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236618/discussion-between-kahngjoonk-and-mark-tolonen).